# How to move content to right side using flexbox in React native

Tags: react-native

I am working on React native, In my project In one View tag I have two Text tags how to move the second text tag to the right side using flex box. But I have to move it to the right side by only using flex box not padding or margin

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello World</Text>
      <Text>Welcome</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: https://medium.com/wix-engineering/the-full-react-native-layout-cheat-sheet-a4147802405c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`justifyContent: 'space-between'` will evenly space all the child components, with the first and last ones on the corresponding ends.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello World</Text>
      <Text>Welcome</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Check the React Native documentation on any topic, it's quite good: 
https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox

Comment: It's space-between not spaceBetween!

Comment: Oh my. You're right, thank you! I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a style to the container like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between', //this will push them to left and right
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10,
  },
});
```

Or if you want to simply specify that you want that specific element to the right you can use `justifyContent: 'flex-end'`

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello World</Text>
      <Text style={{justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>Welcome</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```